# how to overwrite existing data?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have two recyclerview (rvone, rvtwo)
this rvone is the one who displays the data list
when the rvone item is clicked, the value of the data decreases
an example of this item

title
Rp.1000 X 4 pcs
a total of 4000

well, if it's clicked it must be
title
Rp.1000 X 3 pcs
a total of 3000
 Isn't it only reduced by one, that one moved to rvtwo
means it turned out like this

title
Rp.1000 X 1 pcs
a total of 1000

well, the function is already running, but every time it is clicked, even new add is not new to the existing one

here is an example
title
Rp.1000 X 4 pcs
a total of 4000 // this is clicked reduced and the lack is displayed on rvtwo

// means like this
title
Rp.1000 X 1 pcs
a total of 1000

and rvone becomes
title
Rp.1000 X 3 pcs
a total of 3000

When I click again, it becomes like this
rvone:
title
Rp.1000 X 2 pcs
2000 total

rvtwo:
title
Rp.1000 X 1 pcs
a total of 1000

title
Rp.1000 X 1 pcs
a total of 1000

instead it becomes two items instead of overwriting it before
**note : i just add code of constructor and bindViewHolder**

this is my rvone_adapter function onclick to send data to rvtwo

```
public class OrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderAdapter.OrderViewHolder> {

    List<OrderModel> orderModels;
    public List<OrderCatchModel> orderCatchModels = new ArrayList<>();
    List<OrderDetailModel> orderDetailModels;
    Context context;
    OrderCatchAdapter orderCatchAdapter;

    OrderActivity orderActivity;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, List<OrderModel> orderModels,List<OrderDetailModel> orderDetailModels){
        this.context = context;
        this.orderModels = orderModels;
        this.orderDetailModels = orderDetailModels;
    }
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final OrderViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final OrderModel orderModel = orderModels.get(0);

        final Long id = orderModel.getOrderDetailModels().get(position).getId();
        final String itemName = orderModel.getOrderDetailModels().get(position).getItem();
        final long price = orderModel.getOrderDetailModels().get(position).getPrice();
        final long quantity = orderModel.getOrderDetailModels().get(position).getQuantity();
        //final long amount = orderModel.getOrderDetailModels().get(position).getAmount();

        holder.mTxt_item.setText(orderModel.getOrderDetailModels().get(position).getItem());
        holder.mTxt_price.setText("Rp. " + orderModel.getOrderDetailModels().get(position).getPrice());
        holder.mTxt_quantity.setText(orderModel.getOrderDetailModels().get(position).getQuantity() + " Pcs");
        holder.mTxt_amount.setText("Rp. " + orderModel.getOrderDetailModels().get(position).getAmount());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (quantity == 0){
                    orderModels.get(0).getOrderDetailModels().remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(position,orderModels.get(0).getOrderDetailModels().size());
                }else {

                    long q1 = quantity - 1;
                    long a1 = q1 * price;

                    orderModel.getOrderDetailModels().get(position).setQuantity(q1);
                    orderModel.getOrderDetailModels().get(position).setAmount(a1);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();


                    OrderCatchModel orderCatchModel = new OrderCatchModel();
                    orderCatchModel.setId(id);
                    orderCatchModel.setItem(itemName);
                    orderCatchModel.setPrice(price);
                    orderCatchModel.setQuantity(quantity - q1);
                    orderCatchModel.setAmount((quantity - q1) * price);

                    orderCatchModels.add(orderCatchModel);


                    if (context instanceof OrderActivity) {
                        ((OrderActivity)context).addItemToRvTwo(orderCatchModels, orderModel.getOrderDetailModels(), orderModels);
                    }


                }


            }
        });
    }
```

this is my rvtwo_adapter function onclick to sendback data from rvtwo to rvone

```
public OrderCatchAdapter(Context context, List<OrderCatchModel> orderCatchModel, List<OrderDetailModel> orderDetailModels, List<OrderModel> orderModels){
        this.context = context;
        this.orderDetailModels = orderDetailModels;
        this.orderCatchModels = orderCatchModel;
        this.orderModels = orderModels;
    }
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderCatchViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final OrderCatchModel orderCatchModel = orderCatchModels.get(position);

        final Long id = orderCatchModel.getId();
        final String itemName = orderCatchModel.getItem();
        final long price = orderCatchModel.getPrice();
        final long quantity = orderCatchModel.getQuantity();

        holder.mTxt_item.setText(orderCatchModel.getItem());
        holder.mTxt_price.setText("Rp. " + orderCatchModel.getPrice());
        holder.mTxt_quantity.setText(orderCatchModel.getQuantity() + " Pcs");
        holder.mTxt_amount.setText("Rp. " + orderCatchModel.getAmount());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (quantity <= 0){
                    orderCatchModels.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(position,orderCatchModels.size());
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else {
                    long q1 = quantity - 1;
                    long a1 = q1 * price;

                    orderCatchModel.setQuantity(q1);
                    orderCatchModel.setAmount(a1);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

//                    Long idItem = orderModels.get(0).getOrderDetailModels().get(position).getId();

                    OrderDetailModel orderDetailModel = new OrderDetailModel();
                    orderDetailModel.setId(id);
                    orderDetailModel.setItem(itemName);
                    orderDetailModel.setPrice(price);
                    orderDetailModel.setQuantity(quantity - q1);
                    orderDetailModel.setAmount((quantity - q1) * price);

                    orderDetailModels.add(orderDetailModel);


                    if (context instanceof OrderActivity) {
                        ((OrderActivity)context).addDataToRvOne(orderModels, orderDetailModels);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

this is my activity

```
public void addDataToRvOne(List<OrderModel> orderModels, List<OrderDetailModel> orderDetailModels) {
        orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(this, orderModels,orderDetailModels);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManagerRvOne = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        rv_one.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManagerRvOne);
        rv_one.setAdapter(orderAdapter);

        orderAdapter.notifyItemInserted(itemPosition);
        itemPosition += 1;
    }


    public void addItemToRvTwo(List<OrderCatchModel> orderCatchModels, List<OrderDetailModel> orderDetailModels, List<OrderModel> orderModels) {
        orderCatchAdapter = new OrderCatchAdapter(this, orderCatchModels,orderDetailModels, orderModels);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManagerRvTwo = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        rv_two.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManagerRvTwo);
        rv_two.setAdapter(orderCatchAdapter);


        orderCatchAdapter.notifyItemInserted(itemPosition);
        itemPosition += 1;

    }
```

this the model to throw item rv_one

```
public class OrderDetailModel implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String item;
    private long price;
    private long quantity;
    private long amount;

    public OrderDetailModel(
            Long id,
            String item,
            long price,
            long quantity
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.item = item;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.amount = price * quantity;
    }

    public OrderDetailModel() {

    }
```

this model rv_two to catch item rv_one

```
public class OrderCatchModel implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String item;
    private long price;
    private long quantity;
    private long amount;

    public OrderCatchModel(Long id, String item, long price, long quantity, long amount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.item = item;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public OrderCatchModel() {
    }
```

this is the dummydata

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public class MockData {
    public static List<OrderModel> ORDER_MODELS;

    static {
        ORDER_MODELS = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            order(
                    1L,
                    "#00000001-001",
                    new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").parse("21-08-2019 09:47"),
                    null,
                    "MJ002",
                    "Sugiyono",
                    Arrays.asList(
                            new OrderDetailModel(
                                    1L,
                                    "Nasi Goreng",
                                    10000,
                                    2
                            ),
                            new OrderDetailModel(
                                    2L,
                                    "Bubur Ayam",
                                    9000,
                                    4
                            ),
                            new OrderDetailModel(
                                    3L,
                                    "Bubur Kacang",
                                    5000,
                                    5
                            ),
                            new OrderDetailModel(
                                    4L,
                                    "Jus Alpukat",
                                    8000,
                                    6
                            ),
                            new OrderDetailModel(
                                    5L,
                                    "Jus Durian",
                                    15000,
                                    2
                            ),
                            new OrderDetailModel(
                                    6L,
                                    "Jus Apel",
                                    13000,
                                    3
                            )
                    )
            );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.wtf(MockData.class.getSimpleName(), ex);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue")
    private static void order(
            Long id,
            String number,
            Date date,
            String customer,
            String table,
            String staff,
            List<OrderDetailModel> orderDetailModels
    ) {
        OrderModel orderModel = new OrderModel();

        orderModel.setId(id);
        orderModel.setNumber(number);
        orderModel.setDate(date);
        orderModel.setCustomer(customer);
        orderModel.setTable(table);
        orderModel.setStaff(staff);
        orderModel.getOrderDetailModels().addAll(orderDetailModels);

        ORDER_MODELS.add(orderModel);
    }
}
```

ask me if you want another code